# Do WCF 3.5 REST endpoints call associated methods asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, asynchronous-wcf-call

When a WCF 3.5 REST endpoint (via **WebServiceHost**) handles a URI request, does it invoke the associated procedure asynchronously?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [WebServiceHost.Open()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.open.aspx) listens to requests from a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!  I don't see this documented at the MSDN link you provided.  Is there another document that explains this ?

Comment: Not an official document, but an accepted Stack Overflow Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932690/wcf-servicehost-oddity-still-alive-even-if-thread-is-dead/932730#932730. Note that `WebServiceHost` and `ServiceHost` are basically the same, where WebServiceHost is tailored for the web.