# Self hosted service thread within client

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to host a service in my client application to expose data to OEM software also embedded in my client.

What threading options are available to? 
At the moment I use the following something similar to:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(...);
var serviceThread = new System.Threading.Thread(host.Open);
serviceThread.Start();
```

The problem I have is after I call serviceThread.Start() I want to check if the service is running, but the service takes a variable amount of time to either start or fail.

Using Thread.Sleep(x) does not seem right. What are the alternatives?

Thanks.

[Edit]

After trying maralfol suggestion I am getting some weird behaviour where my main thread is hijacked until the service times out.

Code:

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(XmlCacheService), new Uri(baseAddress));

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IXmlDataService), new WebHttpBinding(), string.Empty)
  .Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

try { xmlServiceHost.Open(); }
catch (AddressAccessDeniedException)
{
  CreateRegisterDashboardServiceFile();
  this.ShowUserInfoMessage("The dashboard service needs to be registered. Please contact support.");
}


[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class XmlCacheService : IXmlDataService
{
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IXmlDataService
{
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
  Stream GetXmlData(Stream messageBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a WaitHandle? e.g.

```
    var host = new ServiceHost(...);
    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var serviceThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            host.Open();
            waitHandle.Set();
        });
    serviceThread.Start();
    if( !waitHandle.WaitOne(MAX_TIME_TO_WAIT))
    {
        // not started...
    }
    else ..
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) to signal between threads.  (`Thread.Sleep` used below for illustration's sake).

```
class Program
{
    static ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(_ => { Thread.Sleep(1500); Console.WriteLine("Signaling back"); signal.Set(); });
        t.Start();
        signal.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Signal received, done!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF host already runs in a separated thread. You can create an endpoint for metadata to check if your service is running. What about breakpoints in your contract implementation?

```
class MyService
{
    var host = new ServiceHost(...);

    public MyClass()
    {
        host.Open();
    }
}
```

While you have a reference to MyService, your service will be running and your main thread can perform another tasks.

Comment: Thanks, guess I was over thinking it. Having a proper look at ServiceHost I find it has already got everything I need.

Comment: I've made the changes and I'm now just using the host object which is a field in my main wpf window. The host.open(); runs and my app exec's as normal, but when I hit the service my wpf window is hijacked until it seems the service times out. If I change it again to pass host.open to a new thread I get the desired service behaviour again.

Comment: I see Futurist had the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932690/wcf-servicehost-oddity-still-alive-even-if-thread-is-dead

Comment: I am not sure if I understod your current problem. I guess the WPF application is your WCF client. If I am write, the hijacked in your app is normal because your current thread is waiting for the WPF response. Here is what I did in my case:

Comment: I had to comunicate a WPF app with a windows service through WCF. I created the HostService in my service and kept an alive reference to it. In the WPF app side, when I wanted execute the service, I created a new thread which called the service and waited for a response. If I don't create the client thread, my client app is blocked until the response comes

Answer (score 0):

You can use TPL and wait for the Task to be completed to check if your service is running.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                  {
                                      _host = new ServiceHost(typeof (MyService));
                                      _host.Open();
                                  };
        task.Wait();
        CheckHostIsAvailable();
```

Hope it helps!